# Minifying ts/js in Atom editor

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, minify, atom-editor

I am new to Atom editor. I've got installed such packages as *atom-typescript* to generate Javascript from Typescript and *atom-minify* to minify .css and .js files.

Now I am wondering whether or not it is possible to make them work together automatically. The ideal flow I would like to achieve: I write typescript, then it is transpiled into javascript (this part is done by atom-typescript package) and then my fresh .js file should be automatically minified right after creation.

I cannot find any hooks in either package to make them compatible with each other. Yeah, I can manually open and save .js file or call minifier on it in context menu to achieve my goal, but I want it fulfilled automatically without explicit actions from my part. Any ideas/tricks from Atom users?

Comment: Why don't you use a build system like [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/)?

Comment: probably I will. I am new to such stuff and I need some time to get my head around my current topics before moving further to fancy things like gulp :) Lets put it as an option.